# Populating a list (by a button press from another activity)

Tags: android, listview

How do I populate items on my main activity by a button press from another activity? I already have my LayoutAdapter and a PopulateAlarms object but I'm not what to code for the onClick method of my button.

Thanks for the answers but I should of been more specific. This is for an alarm clock app so I want my main to populate when my save button is clicked (which is in another screen). I am unsure of how to make the proper calls to my listview adatper within my code.

```
Button save_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    save_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         // linking save with main
         Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainClockActivity.class);
         //Here I am trying to create a new item on my main 
         intent.putExtra("Alarm",vals);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way the change and update a list from different activities is probably by using SQLite DB. You have to extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` and when implementing the methods use the onCreate to create your table. Than add all the items in the list to the DB with `getWritableDatabse().execSql("Your SQL code here")`. In `onClick` call the method you created to add items to the DB. To read from the DB you can get a `Cursor` object with all the data and use `SimpleCursorAdapter` to show strings like so:

```
Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawSql("SELECT * FROM tableName");
String[] from = { array of all your column names to show on list }
int[] to = { array of res ids in list xml layout file where the data will be shown }
//from and to indexes must match. Adapter will take data from collumn from[0]
//and put it in the TextView pointed by the id in to[0] etc...
SimpleCursorAdaper a = new SimpleCursorAdapter(..., from, to)
list.setAdapter(a)
```

Last thing - to make the changes visible when you press the back button and go back to the main activity, you might want to adjust the adapter in `onStart`.

Another option is by using intent:

```
onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("keyName", variable);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: My question is actually regarding intents, i have updated my question to better reflect my problem. thank you

Comment: I assume you start `SettingsActivity` with and intent from `MainClockActivity`. In thats case, you dont want to create new intent and open another activity of `MainClockActivity` - It will create a 2nd `MainClockActivity`. What you want is to close `SettingsActivity`, go back to the main screen and see the saved resutls. If i'm following you, you want to start `SettingsActivity` with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities), and send back the results with `getIntent()` and `setResult()` in `SettingsActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You either need to start the secondary [Activity for result](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivityForResult) and populate based on the result or use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) and an interface with the callback you want. If you're using [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html), don't. It's deprecated.

If I've misunderstood your questions and you're just trying to pass some data when you start the secondary Activity, you'll need to use [Extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).